# "Adapt himself to being/be free"

Tags: grammar

A sentence from my reference book is

> He can't adapt himself to **being** free again.

Why is *being* used instead of *be*? Isn't `verb` form and not `verb + ing` form used after *to*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verbs, when combined with *-ing*, form nouns. For example:

> Jogging is good for health. Vitamins are good for health.

Both *jogging* and *vitamins* are nouns.

Consider this sentence, in which *environment* is a noun:

> Some insects are able to adapt themselves to new environments.

In the sentence in the question, "being free again" is a noun phrase. Its use as a noun may be clearer in this sentence:

> Being free again felt wonderful.

The to+verb form, or the infinitive form of the verb, is not the one being used in the example. In the sentence in the example, *to* is used not as part of an infinitive but as a preposition. You would be answering the question: What can't he adapt himself to?

Comment: Oh, *a noun phrase*!

Answer (score 3):

Very simple answer - always use the -ing form and never an infinitive (e.g. - *to be*) after a preposition. Here *to* is a preposition. That's really all there is to it. Apart from working out when *to* is a preposition and when it's part of the infinitive. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.
First, when you use the verb itself after *to*, you are referring to sentences like

> He wanted to eat chocolate,

in which *to* and *eat* are grouped. However in the example sentence, it is *adapt* and *to* that are grouped.

Second, in the example, *being* should be used and not *be* to mean that he already is living in the state of freedom. The sentence

> He can't adapt himself to be free

is also valid but has another meaning - he cannot change himself so that he can be free. In this case, *to be free* should be seen as a phrase.

Comment: Your last sentence (beginning 'Second') makes no sense to me at all.